# What is this called: $ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = $ ... Laplacian?

Tags: partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

$ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}  = \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}       + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}     + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) $

I have seen this and was told by someone random that it is called laplacian... something and since then I couldn't figure it out. Does anyone know what it would be called?

Thanks

Comment: You sure they didn't mean *Laplacian*?  I myself have been known to confuse *Lagrange* with *Laplace*! ;-)

Comment: yes that is probably what I meant thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator

Comment: derivation of the above https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/21C.w11/polar-lap.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is called Laplacian. This will be important in mechanics, wave theory, quantum mechanics, and more. It is defined as the divergence (denoted by $\nabla\cdot$) of the gradient (denoted by $\nabla f$). Visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator to learn more. I am just going to write a couple of formulas for determining Laplacian.

**Two dimensions:**

The formula for the Laplacian in polar coordinates is:
$$\nabla^2 f=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}$$

In Cartesian Coordinates, given a scalar field $f(x, y)$, the Laplacian of $f$ is:
$$\nabla^2 f=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$$

**Three dimensions:**

In Cartesian Coordinates, given a scalar field $f(x, y, z)$, the Laplacian of $f$ is:
$$\nabla^2 f=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}$$

In cylindrical coordinates, given a scalar field $f(\rho, \theta, z)$, the Laplacian is:
$$\nabla^2 f=\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(\rho \frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\right)+\frac{1}{\,\rho^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \varphi^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}$$

In spherical coordinates, given a scalar field $f(r, \theta, \varphi)$, the Laplacian is:
$$\nabla^2 f=\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \varphi^2}$$

They are fairly complicated formulas, but they are there in case you need them. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Another common symbol is $\Delta$

Comment: The problem with $\Delta\equiv\nabla^2$ is that $\Delta f$ most often means change in $f$. Not a very good idea in my opinion. I can't see what's wrong with $\nabla^2$. There's a tendency in modern mathematics to over abbreviate which I find very irritating.